# window.pageYOffsetについて

Tags: javascript

**ブラウザで使用する場合、pageYOffsetではなく、window.pageYOffsetと書いた方が良いケースはありますか？**
・短く書けるのでpageYOffsetの方が良いかなと思ったのですが…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.`を省略しても動作は変わりませんが、省略しない方が`window`のプロパティであることが明確になるので、可読性が高くなる(場合がある)ということだと思います。

【参考】
[What's the purpose of referencing the window object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041666/whats-the-purpose-of-referencing-the-window-object-in-javascript)